# Remove all the non-angle-bracketed words using a Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

Given text

```
my $line = "[cytokine]<ADJVNT-PROP-0> signaling, which have not [to]<PREP> date been shown [to]<PREP> be [[regulat]<EXP-V-0>ed]<EXP-PP-V-0>";
my $line2 = "[Human [papillomavirus]<VACC-PROP-0>]<VACC-PROP-0> genotype [31]<NUM> does not [express]<EXP-V-0> detectable [microRNA]<MIR-0> levels [during]<PREP> latent or productive virus replication.";
```

What I want to do is to remove everything that is not `<XXX>`
resulting this:

```
Output 1: <ADJVNT-PROP-0><PREP><PREP><EXP-V-0><EXP-PP-V-0>
Output 2: <VACC-PROP-0><VACC-PROP-0><NUM><EXP-V-0><MIR-0><PREP>
```

But why did this regex fail? What's the right way to do it?

```
s/[^<.*>]//g
```

This is the full code and executable: https://eval.in/50996

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
s/[^<]*(<[^>]+>)[^<]*/$1/g;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your substitution `s/[^<.*>]//g` uses a *character class*, which matches any *single character* which is not an open or close angle bracket, a dot, or a star. So it will delete all such characters leaving only the ones that are one of those four.

There is a strange passion for trying to write a *single regex* that does everything that solves an entire problem. It is far easier here just to find all strings contained in angle brackets and join them together, like this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my $line = "[cytokine]<ADJVNT-PROP-0> signaling, which have not [to]<PREP> date been shown [to]<PREP> be [[regulat]<EXP-V-0>ed]<EXP-PP-V-0>";
my $line2 = "[Human [papillomavirus]<VACC-PROP-0>]<VACC-PROP-0> genotype [31]<NUM> does not [express]<EXP-V-0> detectable [microRNA]<MIR-0> levels [during]<PREP> latent or productive virus replication.";

say join '', $line  =~ /<[^<>]*>/g;
say join '', $line2 =~ /<[^<>]*>/g;
```

**output**

```
<ADJVNT-PROP-0><PREP><PREP><EXP-V-0><EXP-PP-V-0>
<VACC-PROP-0><VACC-PROP-0><NUM><EXP-V-0><MIR-0><PREP>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it as well.

```
s/[^><]+?(?=<|$)//g;
```

See [working demo](https://eval.in/51035)